# ec2 instance different behaviour on each machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, networking, amazon-ec2, telnet

Recently I am encountering an issue with one of the ec2 machines where I am unable to do curl or telnet.

One ec2 machine with same config and same subnet is working as expected. Other machines not connecting.  even curl request is also not working. I have verified other domains it's working as expected.

example :
On one ec2 machine

```
ubuntu@xxxxx-a1:~$ telnet 59.162.167.9 80
Trying 59.162.167.9...
Connected to 59.162.167.9.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

on other machines even after creating the image from the first machine

```
ubuntu@xxxxx-a4:~$ telnet 59.162.167.9 80
Trying 59.162.167.9...
```

even curl request is also not working. I have verified other domains its working as expected.

Our public IP is the same for all machines which are configured at nat gateway.

```
ubuntu@xxxxx-a4:~$ curl -v http://api-openhouse.imimobile.com/1/obd/thirdpartycall/callSessions
Trying 59.162.167.9...
```

on the first machine

```
ubuntu@xxxxx-a1:~$ curl -v http://api-openhouse.imimobile.com/1/obd/thirdpartycall/callSessions
Trying 59.162.167.9...
Connected to api-openhouse.imimobile.com (59.162.167.9) port 80 (#0)
GET /1/obd/thirdpartycall/callSessions HTTP/1.1
Host: api-openhouse.imimobile.com
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: /
< HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
< Server: nginx
< Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2019 16:30:47 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
Connection #0 to host api-openhouse.imimobile.com left intact
```

Verified my public ip

```
ubuntu@xxxx-a1:~$ curl ifconfig.co
34.194.201.11
ubuntu@xxxxx-a4:~$ curl ifconfig.co
34.194.201.11
```

I have validated different approaches and verified network and security-related issues but didn't succeed, even I have created new image still it didn't work.

One ec2 machine with same config and same subnet is working as expected. Other machines not connecting.  even curl request is also not working. I have verified other domains it's working as expected.

Comment: Can you provide security group names, public IPs (you can cut last digits) and subnets for both machines?